# Can I deploy a Firebase https callable (.onCall) using Terraform?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

So AFAIK, all triggered cloud functions can essentially be deployed using google deploy command which in turn allows me to deploy through terraform through similar parametrization. That being said, I can't seem to deploy a https callable function with:

```
event_trigger {     
    event_type = "https.onCall"     
    resource = "" 
}
```

My assumption is that it's because https callables are explicitly a firebase only "system".

Has anyone gone through this kind of situation before?

Answer (score 4):

[Firebase's callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) are just HTTPS functions that follow a [special protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).  The function-side wrapper around that is provided by the firebase-functions SDK and deployed only by the Firebase CLI.  If you can't use the Firebase CLI, you're going to have a hard time coming up with an equivalent way to deploy that code.  It might be easier to just code your own protocol on both the client and function and deploy with the tools that are compatible with your deployment process.